# Spring boot access multipart request (file upload) headers before request completes

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data

Is there a way I can check the Authorization header before the request completes? I do not want to start accepting the file upload if the user is not authenticated. My code is:

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/uploadLogo", produces = "application/json", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ApiResponse handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request){
  System.out.println(request.getHeader("Authorization")); 
  ...
```

This works only after the file is uploaded.

Comment: "just" add `.mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/uploadLogo").authenticated()` (in the right place..somewhere top;) to your "configurer"

Comment: (..i.e.  ensure it is not `permitAll()`.) ... and you can also use `@AuthenticationPrincipal/Principal` objects as controller params! [see here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) [and here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/mvc.html#mvc-authentication-principal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTTP filters. But this won't avoid the file being uploaded.
The HTTP filters will intercept the request before reaching the controller. If you think the request is correct (with the adequate credentials) you continue to the controller, otherwise, throw an exception.

I share you my repository where I've implemented the authentication via JWT on the HTTP filters: https://github.com/serlesen/backend-social-network/tree/chapter_3

Comment: Using filters is a good way to go and I like your implementation, I was just wondering if I could reject the rest of the request after I had accessed the header and authenticate the user, but maybe the full request has to be received in order to get access to it. Thank you!

Comment: The request must be received completely to be processed: header + body + files. With the HTTP filters, you can avoid getting inside the controller if the authentication isn't correct, thus, is a good way to have a single point to validate the authentication instead of repeating those checks on each endpoint